# What are the equivalents of .split() and .rstrip() for a tuple?

Tags: python

I have a tuple that looks like this:

```
('1 2130 0 279 90 92 193 1\n', '1 186 0 299 14 36 44 1\n')
```

And i want to split it so that each column will be seperate so i can access it in an easier way.

So for an example:

```
tuple[0][2]
```

would return `0`

```
tuple[1][3]
```

would return `299`

The second part of my question is what is the equivalent of `.rstrip()` 
so i can get rid of the `\n`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use a list comprehension:

```
rows = [row.split() for row in your_tuple]
```

As for `.rstrip()`, you don't need it. `.split()` (with no argument!) takes care of that for you:

```
>>> '    a    b  c \t\n\n   '.split()
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Answer (score 2):

Apply `str.split` to each item of  the tuple:

```
>>> tup = ('1 2130 0 279 90 92 193 1\n', '1 186 0 299 14 36 44 1\n')
>>> t = map(str.split, tup)
>>> t
[['1', '2130', '0', '279', '90', '92', '193', '1'], ['1', '186', '0', '299', '14', '36', '44', '1']]

>>> t[0][2]
'0'
>>> t[1][3]
'299'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> data = ('1 2130 0 279 90 92 193 1\n', '1 186 0 299 14 36 44 1\n')    
>>> [x.split() for x in data]
[['1', '2130', '0', '279', '90', '92', '193', '1'],
 ['1', '186', '0', '299', '14', '36', '44', '1']]
```

If you want integer values:

```
>>> [[int(y) for y in x.split()] for x in data]
[[1, 2130, 0, 279, 90, 92, 193, 1], [1, 186, 0, 299, 14, 36, 44, 1]]

>>> res = [[int(y) for y in x.split()] for x in data]
>>> res[0][1]
2130
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to `split()` or `rstrip()` the tuple. The things in the tuple are strings and these are perfectly splittable and strippable, and so what you want is an easy way to apply those operations to *each string* in the tuple. (Actually, you don't need the `rstrip()` as the `split()` will take care of the newline for you.) This is where list comprehensions come in:

```
data = ('1 2130 0 279 90 92 193 1\n', '1 186 0 299 14 36 44 1\n')
data = [x.split() for x in data]
```

Now this ends up with the tuple (and its elements) being a list. This is fine most of the time, but if you really need it to be a tuple, not a list, try this:

```
data = tuple(tuple(x.split()) for x in data)
```

Answer (score 0):

use a list comprehension:

```
rows = [row.split() for row in tuple]
```

You can use:

```
each_item[:-1]
```

To get rid of the `\n`

Comment: ```each_item[:-1]``` can cause issue if \n will not be in item